# ¿Cómo se puede traer un dato de una base de datos a un Select box?

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, aplicación-web

Intento hacer un programa que al registrarse un usuario este se guarde en la base de datos, después la misma página web contiene otra sección que se llama equipos y quisiera traer de la base de datos los nombres de usuarios dados de alta como se muestra en la imagen, pero no me marca error el programa simplemente no me aparece desde donde aparece el código para traerlo hasta abajo, anexare una imagen mostrando donde ya no se muestra el programa completo

```
    <?php
  require_once "Vistas/psuperior.php";
  include 'conexion.php';
?>

 <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-md-4">
      <div class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
        <h1 class="h2">Equipos</h1>
      </div>

  <form action="insertar_equipo.php" method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">No. Serie: </label>
    <input name="txtSerie" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput" placeholder="Serie del equipo">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Marca</label>
    <input name="txtMarca" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Marca del equipo">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Modelo</label>
    <input name="txtModelo" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Modelo del equipo">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="slctEquipo">Tipo de Equipo:</label>
    <select name="txtTipEquipo" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled>Selecciona una Opción</option> 
    <option value="Celular">Celular</option>
    <option value="Desktop">Desktop</option>
    <option value="Laptop">Laptop</option>
    <option value="Proyector">Proyector</option>
    <option value="Impresora">Impresora</option>
    <option value="Otro">Otro</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">IP:</label>
    <input name="txtIp" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="IP del equipo">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Nombre Usuario:</label>
    <select name="txtEmpleadoSoporte" class="form-control">
    <option>Seleccionar...</option> 
      <?php 
      $query = $mysqli -> query ("SELECT nomina, CONCAT(nomUsuario, ' ', correo) AS nombres FROM employees");
                          
      while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
                              
        echo '<option value="'.$valores['nombre'].'">'.$valores['nombre'].'</option>';
      }

      ?>
    </select>
</div>  <!-- A partir de aquí no lo muestra-->
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Número Teléfonico:</label>
    <input name="txtCelular" type="tel" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Teléfono del Usuario">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">RAM:</label>
    <input name="txtRam" type="tel" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="RAM del equipo">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Disco Duro:</label>
    <input name="txtDiscDr" type="tel" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Disco Duro del equipo">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Versión de Software:</label>
    <input name="txtSoft" type="tel" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Versión de Software del equipo">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Office:</label>
    <input name="txtOffice" type="tel" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Office del equipo">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Fecha de Instalación:</label>
    <input name="txtFechai" type="date" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="slctEstatus">Estatus:</label>
    <select name="txtEstatusEquipo" class="form-control">
    <option selected disabled>Selecciona una Opción</option> 
    <option value="Activo">Activo</option>
    <option value="Inactivo">Inactivo</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Comentarios:</label>
    <input name="txtComentarios" type="text" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="Comentarios...">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Fecha de Baja:</label>
    <input name="txtFechaB" type="date" class="form-control" id="formGroupExampleInput2" placeholder="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
<input type="hidden" name="oculto_equipo" value="1";
</div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success" name="btnAsignacion">Guardar Equipo <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke="currentColor" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" class="feather feather-save"><path d="M19 21H5a2 2 0 0 1-2-2V5a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h11l5 5v11a2 2 0 0 1-2 2z"></path><polyline points="17 21 17 13 7 13 7 21"></polyline><polyline points="7 3 7 8 15 8"></polyline></svg></button>
  </div>
</form>
      
    </main>
```

Este es el código de mi conexion.php

```
<?php 
$host="localhost";
$user="root";
$pass="";
$nombrebd="usuarios";

try{
$bd=new PDO(
    'mysql:host=localhost;
    dbname='.$nombrebd,
    $user,
    $pass
);
    }
catch (Exception $e){
echo "Error de conexión".$e->getMessage();
}
 ?>
```

Agradecería cualquier ayuda

[image: Pantalla del menú y donde no aparecen los datos ya dados de alta]

Comment: Tu estás conectado a `PDO` (último bloque de código) y luego usas `mysqli` (para crear los option). Si conectas a PDO lo lógico es que uses código de PDO. Entonces, o migras la forma de lanzar las consultas, o conectas a `mysqli`, pues `PDO` y `mysqli` son dos cosas distintas, no puedes mezclarlas.

Comment: Ya lo corregí y funciono, muchas gracias